# .onsubmit редиректит на php файл даже если return false

Tags: jquery

подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема: если делаю .onsubmit не в теге формы, то выполняется аякс, но все равно идет редирект на php файл, а если я в теге пишу onsubmit="return function()", он оставляет текущую страницу(как я и хочу).

получается, если делать с тела формы, мы получаем onsubmit= "return false", а если делать через JQ onsubmit = "false". играет ли это какою-то роль?

код JQ

```
$( function () {
$( '#formEnter' ).on( 'submit', function (event) {
    $.ajax( (
                {
                    type:    'POST',
                    url:     'login.php',
                    data:    $( '#formEnter' ).serialize(),
                    success: function (datafromserverenter) {
                        let data = JSON.parse( datafromserverenter );
                        if ( data.uspeh1 == 'yes' ) {
                            $( '#formEnterDivDiv' ).text( 'Dobro Pojalovat' );
                        }
                        if ( data.uspeh2 == 'no' ) {
                            $( '#failLogin' ).text( 'fail login or pass' );
                        }

                    }
                }
            ) );

} );
return false;
} );
```

соответственно, если это обернуть в функцию и вызвать ее в тэге form, то редиректа не будет.

Comment: Зачем вообще вызывать метод `submit` формы если в итоге нужно его же и предотвратить и отправить всё аяксом? Где логика в таком действии? Это же бессмыслица.

Comment: нашел решение через preventDefault.

Comment: @СергейМишин  читая Ваше сообщение, осознал наконец-то правильную работу аякса. как Вы уже поняли,я не очень то опытный в этом вопросе.но в любом случае большое спасибо.

Comment: В вашем случае проще сделать просто кнопку и повесить обработчик клика на неё. Тогда и никаких preventDefault или return false; делать не надо.

Comment: @СергейМишин теперь я это понял. но раньше я думал, что суть аякса в том, что он забирает с сервера данные переданные сабмитом. теерь я понимаю, что это не так, и что нужно больше литературы.